# Would be possible to create your own "PhoneGap Cloud Builder" with the OpenSource version?

Tags: ios, cordova

We know there is the PhoneGap Cloud Builder. Essentially, they compile your app in their own servers using PhoneGap.

Would be possible to build our own "Phonegap cloud builder" using the community version ? ,

I´m talking about technical feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is more than feasible. Besides the build.phonegap.com site there are others who've done the same thing like:

http://www.icenium.com/